# Need to Combine Query with Distinct and Count

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

I have a query that I'm trying to clean up:

My original query is as follows:

```
SELECT h.userid, c.firstname, c.lastname, h.domain, h.nextduedate, h.domainstatus, 
    (SELECT COUNT(status) 
     FROM tblinvoices i, tblinvoiceitems ii
     WHERE i.userid =h.userid
            AND i.id = ii.invoiceid
        AND i.STATUS LIKE  'Unpaid'
        AND i.TOTAL = 80
        AND ii.description LIKE  'Hosted Domain%')
     AS invoice_count 
 FROM tblclients c, tblhosting h 
 WHERE h.userid=c.id AND c.status='Active' 
    AND c.id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    AND h.domain LIKE '%thisdomain.com' 
    AND h.nextduedate<='2012-06-06' 
 ORDER BY h.domainstatus, h.nextduedate DESC
```

It works fairly well, but it isn't 100% accurate.  I'm getting all of the users with a "nextduedate" that is older than today's date, but, there are some users with Unpaid invoices with a NULL nextduedate (account is cancelled, but they still have unpaid invoices).

This query gives me 22 users, but if I run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.userid, COUNT(i.status) 
     FROM tblinvoices i, tblinvoiceitems ii
     WHERE i.id = ii.invoiceid
        AND i.STATUS LIKE  'Unpaid'
        AND i.TOTAL = 80
        AND ii.description LIKE  'Hosted Domain%')
```

Then I get 26 users (and about 8 missing invoices).

The Next Due Date is really to show how late they are, the main focus of this query is to show all of the users with Unpaid invoices.  I tried to combined the second query with the first one several different ways, but I can't figure it out, and I think I locked up my server.

Ideally my return row would look like this:

userid, firstname, lastname, domain, domainstatus, "duedate" (this would ideally be the date of the oldest invoice, I'm using nextduedate because it's easy), invoicecount (the number of unpaid invoices)

FYI, the invoice date is in i.invoicedate

I would greatly appreciate help figuring out how to optimize this query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to replace `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT h.userid, c.firstname, c.lastname, h.domain, h.nextduedate, h.domainstatus, count(i.status) AS invoice_count

FROM tblclients c, tblhosting h 
LEFT JOIN tblinvoices i ON i.userid =h.userid         
    AND i.STATUS LIKE  'Unpaid'
    AND i.TOTAL = 80
LEFT JOIN tblinvoiceitems ii ON i.id = ii.invoiceid
    AND ii.description LIKE  'Hosted Domain%'


WHERE h.userid=c.id AND c.status='Active' 
    AND c.id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    AND h.domain LIKE '%thisdomain.com' 
    AND h.nextduedate<='2012-06-06'
GROUP BY h.userid 
ORDER BY h.domainstatus, h.nextduedate DESC
```

Comment: I can see making that change on the send query, but that query already works by itself.  I tried to use the GROUP BY when I merged the two queries, but I could not figure out how to do it correctly to give me all of the information I needed.  Actually, I never got it to work at all with anything other than the COUNT (status) as in the original query.

Comment: This was my attempt to combine the two queries
`SELECT h.userid, c.firstname, c.lastname, h.domain, h.nextduedate, h.domainstatus, i.userid, COUNT(i.status) 
 FROM tblclients c, tblhosting h, tblinvoices i, tblinvoiceitems ii 
 WHERE h.userid=c.id AND c.status='Active' 
 AND c.id NOT IN (1,2,3,4) 
 AND h.domain LIKE '%domain.com' 
        AND i.userid =h.userid
  AND i.id = ii.invoiceid 
  AND i.STATUS LIKE  'Unpaid' 
  AND i.TOTAL = 80 
  AND ii.description LIKE  'Hosted%' 
 AND h.nextduedate<='2012-06-06' 
        GROUP BY i.userid 
 ORDER BY h.domainstatus, h.nextduedate DESC`

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you very much, I used what you gave me and took it s step further to pull out the date of the first invoice due!  Thanks!!